# Restrict usage of parameterless constructor to serialization/Activator/new()

Tags: c#

I've always had the following question in my mind and couldn't find the question on SO:

How can I have my default constructor for Serialization/Activator purposes, while making sure a consumer is discouraged/disabled from using it?

In the past I've used hints like

```
///<summary>
/// Do not use the default constructor
///</summary>
```

which are obviously overlooked easily, unless you carefully hover and check every class you use.

While I would get better visual indication like this:

```
[Obsolete("Do not use the default constructor")]
```

it would be a complete abuse of the feature which leaves me shivering.

Is there any common way I'm not aware of to deal with this, or is it just me who feels annoyed by this in the first place?

Comment: can you use private constructor?

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala no. That works for neither activator nor serialization

Comment: @DovydasSopa This does not work for Activator. Please read the question before false flagging

Comment: @Dbl Yea.. I read "Serialization-only constuctor"

Comment: @DovydasSopa good point actually. I've edited the question to clarify. Thanks

Comment: @Dbl `Activator.CreateInstance` [has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he47tyc4(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows it to use a private parameterless constructor.  Most serializers would work, too.

Comment: You are not tagging your question with wcf or anything. So my doubts are why do you need *special* constructor for a simple serializable class (which is normally DTO-alike)? Maybe that class is doing *too much* and you simply need refactoring? Would be nice to read about practical reasoning (aka what this class is used for).

Comment: @CharlesMager While this is nice and i wasn't aware of it yet, this unfortunately does not work for PCL. I'm looking for a broader solution. Thanks for the effort however

Comment: @Sinatr Let's say i have a ViewModel, which has to be serializable / creatable through Activator - If it depends on 2 Id's for loading information i want to ensure that those 2 id's will always be present and valid i am bound to use a special constructor. The biggest reason would be Activator usage here, but comment char limit would be inadequate to explain the reasoning. I am pretty certain however you would be inclined to agree with the practical reasoning.

Comment: BinaryFormatter does not call *any* constructor fyi. It uses a special reflection API for that.

Comment: @usr i know. I've only mentioned it for the sake of an example where this is a common "problem". If only FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject would always be an option and the default method of serialization functionality providers :/

Comment: @Dbl, you are doing something wrong. There is no practical need to serialize ViewModel. Serialize Model instead. This is the whole point of MVVM. Do not try to serialize ViewModel (which need some run-time data to be valid = means it is not serializable).

Comment: @Sinatr strictly speaking you are obviously correct about this. However it's an example for situations where it's sometimes convenient to at least have an opportunity to be lazy and not spend half your development time mapping properties/configuring automapper/(fixing/debugging) automapper issues. So yeah - we're on the same page, but this was just an example anyway. Once c#7 is shipped with constructor constraints this will most likely be a non issue anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If your class is within an class library, and the serialization happens from the class library itself, you can create an `internal` wrapper class (deriving from your original class) that exposes the serialization constructor. In that way, you can make sure nothing from the outside is calling that constructor. With this approach, you have to use that wrapper type when deserializing.

That would still mean the constructor can be called from inside the class library of course, but it prevents most of the unintended use.

Comment: Very nice answer. This certainly covers the most common serialization issue regarding the matter.